# Why binary search algorithm doesn't work if i use two "if" statements rather than only a "if/else" statement?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, if-statement, binary-search

This code block works perfectly . This is a binary search algorithm written in javascript. I collected it from a website.

```js
function binarySearch(arr, target) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = arr.length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        const mid = left + Math.floor((right - left) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] === target) {
            return mid;
        }
        if (arr[mid] < target) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var result = binarySearch([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2);
console.log(result);
```

But if i change the code inside the while loop this way it doesn't work .
I have tried several times but to no avail. Please help me. What is the problem?

```js
function binarySearch(arr, target) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = arr.length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        const mid = left + Math.floor((right - left) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] === target) {
            return mid;
        }

        if (arr[mid] < target) {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        // Look here. Here is my problem
        if(arr[mid] > target){
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var result = binarySearch([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @VLAZ Can you please explain this more?

Comment: Your second if your going to need `>=` or have a dead zone that you didn't have with the `if else`

Comment: He handles the equals case separately.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn you're right. Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: When you say it works or doesn’t work, could you provide a sample input that works with the first function but fails with the second?

Comment: There are three if statements that can be used for three specific condition. only one if statement will execute during each iteration of the loop. I dont know where i am wrong. pls clarify.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn . Here is the code sample. https://repl.it/repls/TrickyFoolhardyMicrobsd

Comment: I tried both your functions and they gave the same results.

Comment: you inversed the content of the if blocks in your live example compared to here

Comment: Same here, both functions work for me too.   OP, can you clarify on what you mean doesn't work?

Comment: @sakib1212 You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to post executable code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (arr[mid] === target) {
    return mid;
}

if (arr[mid] < target) {
    left = mid + 1;
}

if(arr[mid] > target){
    right = mid - 1;
}
```

and

```
if (arr[mid] === target) {
    return mid;
}

if (arr[mid] < target) {
    left = mid + 1;
} else {
    right = mid - 1;
}
```

Are equivalent in this scenario.

Comment: He expected them to be equivalent. His question states that they aren't, and asks why. You didn't answer that question.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking, for some strange reason he say's the second version doesn't work,.  But it appears it does, work.

Comment: Sorry everybody. I have tested it on browser putting the code on a js file. It was the fault of the repl code editor. It didn't show the correct result

Comment: And i am a first timer on stackoverflow. I didn't expect this first reply from you guys. It was amazing. Best wishes for you guys